# EWS Managed API. Пользовательские свойства

Tags: c#, сервер, api, exchange, ews

В Outlook у Контакта есть свойства User1, User2, User3 и User4. Нужно получить их значения через EWS, но они не включены в определение класса Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Contact.

Подскажите пожалуста их PID-ы, что бы извлечь данные через определения этих свойств. Что-то у меня не получается их найти.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc815885.aspx

```
    public static ExtendedPropertyDefinition PidLidContactUserField1 = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.Address, 0x804F, MapiPropertyType.String);
    public static ExtendedPropertyDefinition PidLidContactUserField2 = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.Address, 0x8050, MapiPropertyType.String);
    public static ExtendedPropertyDefinition PidLidContactUserField3 = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.Address, 0x8051, MapiPropertyType.String);
    public static ExtendedPropertyDefinition PidLidContactUserField4 = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.Address, 0x8052, MapiPropertyType.String);
```